# Get all similar casenum on one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query:

```
CREATE TABLE cases AS
SELECT 
   casenum
FROM cases;

CREATE TABLE programs AS
SELECT
   casenum
   ,CASE
      WHEN prgm_cd='ra' THEN 'y'
      ELSE NULL
   END AS resea
   ,CASE
      WHEN prgm_cd='tf' THEN 'y'
      ELSE NULL
   END AS tanf
   ,CASE
      WHEN prgm_cd='ta' THEN 'y'
      ELSE NULL
   END AS taa
FROM prgms;

SELECT 
   casenum
   ,resea
   ,tanf
   ,taa
FROM cases
LEFT JOIN programs on cases.casenum = programs.casenum;
```

The results:

| casenum | resea | tanf | taa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100201 | y |  |  |
| 100201 |  | y |  |
| 100201 |  |  | y |

If a case has only one of the programs then it will only have one row. If a case has two programs then it will have two rows. And if the case has three rows it will have three rows.

What I want:
I want one row for one case no matter what program(s) they are in. So the example above would look like this:

| casenum | resea | tanf | taa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100201 | y | y | y |

I tried taking out the else null in the case expressions and it added many more rows. The previous example looked like this:

| casenum | resea | tanf | taa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100201 | y | y | y |
| 100201 | y |  |  |
| 100201 |  | y |  |
| 100201 |  |  | y |
| 100201 |  |  |  |
| 100201 | y | y |  |
| 100201 |  | y | y |
| 100201 | y |  | y |

I tried adding `rownum() over(partition by casenum order by casenum) rn`. That had all of the results I wanted on row 1 and then when I put it into a sub `select where rn = 1` I did not get the results I was looking for.

Comment: What is the structure of the case and programs tables? Share this information with some sample data.

Comment: does throwing a `GROUP BY` and `MAX` a good measure for the problem?

Comment: Your syntax is not SQL Server? What RDBMS are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Join each program code separately:

```
SELECT
    c.casenum,
    CASE
        WHEN prgm_ra.prgm_cd='ra' THEN 'y'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS resea,
    CASE
       WHEN prgm_tf.prgm_cd='tf' THEN 'y'
       ELSE NULL
    END AS tanf,
    CASE
       WHEN prgm_ta.prgm_cd='ta' THEN 'y'
       ELSE NULL
    END AS taa
FROM cases c
    LEFT JOIN prgms prgms_ra
        ON c.casenum = prgms_ra.casenum and prgms_ra.prgm_cd = 'ra'
    LEFT JOIN prgms prgms_tf
        ON c.casenum = prgms_tf.casenum and prgms_tf.prgm_cd = 'tf'
    LEFT JOIN prgms prgms_ta
        ON c.casenum = prgms_ta.casenum and prgms_ta.prgm_cd = 'ta'
```